# I am creating a portal management form. Now I want to display a new pages for each employee in php

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, portal

I am creating a web portal but I don't understand how to create new dynamical pages for each user after registration in php.

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is general information that you should keep in mind, when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create new page for each user after registration, you have to make a single page that should be shown to user and change its content after registration dynamically, by fetching those data from the database. Fields like profile image, name, email are what you want to change according to what you get from database.

Comment: can you share the code of that single page which generate pages for each users after registrations